# What actually happens when we call ServiceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe()?

Tags: push-notification, push, service-worker, subscribe, web-push

Does the subscribe method set up any sort of connection between the client and the push service? Or is all the necessary information needed to send the message to the correct client stored in the endpoint URL, so that no connection is necessary?

If there's no connection, how would the push service know to update the IP Address if the client moves (changing the IP address)?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `subscribe` the browser connects to the push service (e.g. [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) or [Mozilla push service](https://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) and requests a new endpoint.

Then the *promise* is resolved and you can send that endpoint with AJAX to your own app server (or to a service like [Pushpad](https://pushpad.xyz)). Your server can use that endpoint to send the notifications (it's like an email address).

Finally, every time that the user has the browser open, it connects to GCM, it  authenticates by showing its endpoint (or maybe a secret associated to it) and reads any new notification.

For more details: https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/#sequence-diagram

> If there's no connection, how would the push service know to update the IP Address if the client moves (changing the IP address)?

There must be a connection, otherwise the notifications cannot be delivered. It's not a problem if the IP changes: it's the client that connects to the push service, not vice versa.

*Disclosure: I am the Pushpad founder*

Comment: Notifications can be sent if the browser isn't open, so if the user changes location but doesn't open the browser (so no connection to GCM), are the notifications just not delivered until they do open the browser and make the connection? How does that work?

Comment: @NickSearle You can't use GCM directly to manage location. GCM is very simple and only knows how to deliver a notification to a given endpoint/device. It's your web app/service that must keep track of the user location: at the moment you can update it only when the user is surfing your website or when he receives a push notification.

Comment: It's recommended to call pushManager.getSubscription() whenever the user accesses your app because it's possible for the subscription object to change during its lifetime. Do you know what changes about the subscription object if it can't be any information about the endpoint (because GCM can't know if the endpoint changes)?

Comment: How should one prevent the case that `.subscribe` succeeds but the request to the server storing the new endpoint fails?